# php extension: can not update class field using zend_hash_update

Tags: php, c, php-internals

I want to realize this class into php extension:

```
class MyClass {
  protected $attrs = array();
  public function __construct($id = null) {
    $this->attrs['id'] = $id;
    $this->attrs['name'] = '';
  }
  public function __get($key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->attr)) 
      return $this->attrs[$key];
  }
  public function __set($key, $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->attr)) 
      $this->attrs[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

I've already implemented __constructor, $attrs field, and __get method. And now I can't figure about __set.

There is my c code:

```
PHP_METHOD(MyClass, __set) {    
  char *key;
  int key_len;
  zval *value;  

  if (FAILURE == zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "sz", &key, &key_len, &value)) {
    RETURN_NULL();
  }

  zval *attrs, *obj;
  obj = getThis();
  attrs = zend_read_property(Z_OBJCE_P(obj), obj, "attrs", strlen("attrs"), TRUE, TSRMLS_C);

  if (Z_TYPE_P(attrs) == IS_ARRAY && zend_hash_exists(Z_ARRVAL_P(attrs), key, strlen(key) + 1)) {
    zend_hash_update(Z_ARRVAL_P(attributes), key, strlen(key) + 1, &value, sizeof(zval*), NULL);
    }
  else {        
    zend_throw_exception_ex(zend_exception_get_default(TSRMLS_C), 1, TSRMLS_C, "unknown field \"%s\"", key);
  }
}
```

Where attrs - declared protected property  in init function (I've declared property as null, but when I add data to $attrs in constructor - property updates to be an array)

```
zend_declare_property_null(myclass_ce, "attrs", strlen("attrs"), ZEND_ACC_PROTECTED TSRMLS_CC);
```

So my question is: how I need to update my attr field in c?
My extensions succesfully compiles, I can define properties, read them, but I can't set them - because setted value becomes null, example:

```
class MyClass2 extends MyClass {
  public function __construct($id = null) {
    parent::__construct($id);
    $this->attrs["type"] = "clz";
  }
} 

$c = new MyClass();
var_dump($c->type); // string(3) "clz"
$c->type = "myclz"; // no error, my __set method handles this call, and I'm sure I'm getting correct value 
var_dump($c->type); // NULL
```

I'm new to c development and I really need help.

**UPD 1.** I've tried change __set body to this:

```
zval *strval;
MAKE_STD_ZVAL(strval);
ZVAL_STRING(strval, Z_STRVAL_P(value), TRUE);
if (Z_TYPE_P(attributes) == IS_ARRAY && zend_hash_exists(Z_ARRVAL_P(attributes), key, strlen(key) + 1)) {
  zend_hash_update(HASH_OF(attributes), key, strlen(key) + 1, &strval, sizeof(zval*), NULL);
}
```

And now I can set string values. If I need to make switch on each type of zval??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
PHP_METHOD(MyClass, __set) {    
  char *key;
  int key_len;
  zval *value, *copied;  

  if (FAILURE == zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "sz", &key, &key_len, &value)) {
    RETURN_NULL();
  }

  zval *attrs, *obj;
  obj = getThis();
  attrs = zend_read_property(Z_OBJCE_P(obj), obj, "attrs", strlen("attrs"), TRUE, TSRMLS_C);

  MAKE_STD_ZVAL(copied);
  *copied = *value;
  zval_copy_ctor(copied);

  if (Z_TYPE_P(attrs) == IS_ARRAY && zend_hash_exists(Z_ARRVAL_P(attrs), key, strlen(key) + 1)) {
    zend_hash_update(Z_ARRVAL_P(attributes), key, strlen(key) + 1, &copied, sizeof(zval*), NULL);
  }
  else {        
    zend_throw_exception_ex(zend_exception_get_default(TSRMLS_C), 1, TSRMLS_C, "unknown field \"%s\"", key);
  }
}
```